# Calling id in Laravel Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I use a [Laravel Datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) in Laravel to create a Datatable with filters.I need too a custom column so I add this code:

```
 ->addColumn('estado', function ($previsitas) {
            return $previsitas->f_salida ?  '<a id="delete" class="text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cambiar estado" href="' . route('visitas.estado', [$previsitas->id]) . '"><strong>Salida</strong></a>' :'<a class="text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cambiar estado" href="' . route('visitas.estado', [$previsitas->id]) . '"><strong>Entrada</strong></a>';
        })->rawColumns(['estado'])
```

This code works perfectly. I need too call this column to prompt a message with [sweetalert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert). I use this...

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
    swal('Test');
});
```

When i click in the column nothing happens, but when i create directly element with a id='delete' in the blade works.

So the error is simple: I can´t call a element with id in the datatable column, but i can call the element if directly i use in the blade. Why this error is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use jQuery event delegation for this. Currently, calling `$("#delete").click(...)` assigns a `click` event to the DOM element `$("#delete")`, which at the time of assignment, doesn't exist. If you assign the `click` event to `"body"` with a target of `"#delete"`, this should work for you:

```
$("body").on("click", "#delete", function () {
    swal("Test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
    swal('Test');
});
```

might be executing before

```
->addColumn('estado', function ($previsitas) {
            return $previsitas->f_salida ?  '<a id="delete" class="text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cambiar estado" href="' . route('visitas.estado', [$previsitas->id]) . '"><strong>Salida</strong></a>' :'<a class="text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cambiar estado" href="' . route('visitas.estado', [$previsitas->id]) . '"><strong>Entrada</strong></a>';
        })->rawColumns(['estado'])
```

is added to the DOM

Comment: Forget it, I found the solution. I need  to add this to JS code '$('body').on('click', '#delete', function(){});'